# Any Possibilities to communicate between AngularJS and Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive

Is there any possibilities to communicate angular 2 component form AngularJS app.

For Example : App is created with angularJS for New component if we create in angular 2+, is there any way to communicate between this.

Comment: Yes, plenty. Look e.g. here http://www.codelord.net/2016/01/07/adding-the-first-angular-2-service-to-your-angular-1-app/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Zlatko. I just need to know,If complete component with HTML which is created in angular 2 can we call in Angular 1.x. Please share me example.

Comment: That link has an example Angular service that you can use in AngularJS components. So create one such service and use it in both new and old components to communicate.

Comment: Sure let me try the same and get back to you..